# Separate Date and Time from a DateTime column and put each into it's own Date and Time column

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, time

I have a 'DateTime' column in a MySQL database (Y-m-d H:i:s). To do the query that I want to do I need to separate the date and time and put each into it's own column. I have tried to do so with 'UPDATE' in MySQL and created a new 'Date' and 'Time' column to put the data into. Everything I try puts the data into the column as all zeros. How can I get this data separated into their own columns?

EDIT: right now the query is to see what appointments I have on a particular day. With the datetime column when I do the query let's say 2015-08-19 @ 1:00 PM it brings back just the appointments for that exact date AND time. I want the query to bring back all appointments for a date regardless of the time.

Here is my SELECT statement

```
$appt_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($appt_date));

    $query = $mysqli->prepare("
SELECT set_date
     , branch
     , appt_date
     , employee
     , fname
     , lname
     , last_four
     , phone
     , city
     , state
     , zip 
  FROM appointments 
 WHERE set_date BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."' 
   AND set_date LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
   AND branch LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
   AND appt_date = (?) 
   AND employee LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
   AND fname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
   AND lname LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
   AND last_four LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
   AND phone LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
   AND city LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
   AND state LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
   AND zip LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') 
 ORDER 
    BY set_date ASC
");
```

Comment: Not to avoid the question, but what query could you possibly want to do where you need to separate the datetime into two separate columns in the actual table?

Comment: why would you want two fields? if you want the date or time components, you can trivially do `select time(datetimefield), date(datetimefield)` splitting them up will just lead to pain later, e.g. `timefield=timefield + interval 23 hour`, oops, no you've munged up your date because you didn't do `datefield=datefield+interval 1 day` to account for the timefield changes.

Comment: @MarcB: Can you index on scalar function calls?

Comment: mysql's internal date/time form is easily scannable for this sort of thing with just a single index on the whole field.

Comment: @Strawberry: Sure it is. If he needs to query on the date irrespective of time (finding everything that happened on a certain date, for example), then that's exactly what you'd want to do.

Comment: @TabAlleman: Querying on dates irrespective of time is pretty common. If want to see everything that takes place on a certain day and I have to involve the time, I would have to use a `between` (or `<' and '>') in order to account for the span of time that accounts for that day. If you can query on a date only (either by using a dedicated field or something like `date()` as Marc suggests), you can use a simple equality check.

Comment: @Derek Shouldn't this work for you? `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(colName, '%Y-%m-%d') DATEONLY, 
       DATE_FORMAT(colName,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY`

Comment: @MarcB: I'm not a MySQL dev or dba, so I'm genuinely asking, not being snarky: are you telling me that if I apply a (presumably nonclustered) index to a `DateTime` column, then having something like `where date(MyDateTIme) = '8/14/2015'` would utilize that index and not perform a table scan?

Comment: @Derek: Since nobody is actually addressing the question, please post what you've tried. It makes it easier for people to find a solution if they can see what you've tried rather than just reading that what you've tried hasn't worked.

Comment: Having a date only column allows you to join to a calendar table.

Comment: @DanBracuk Brings up a good point as well. Having a dedicated date column would also permit you to do things like, say, having a unique index on the date column (or use it as the primary key), allowing you to limit the table to one record per day (while still allowing a variation in time).

Comment: @TabAlleman right now the query is to see what appointments I have on a particular day. With the datetime column when I do the query let's say 2015-08-19 @ 1:00 PM it brings back just the appointments for that exact date AND time. I want the query to bring back all appointments for a date regardless of the time. I have put my 'SELECT' statement in my question. If possible let me know how I can do this query for 'appt_date'. Thanks Tab

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes, it would, but it is also more work to express (and is less obvious in its meaning) than a simple equality comparison. Having to say `where MyDateTime >= '8/14/2015' and MyDateTime < '8/15/2015'` is not as clear as `where MyDateTime = '8/14/2015'`

Comment: @Derek: Please post the `update` that you've attempted to use that has failed.

Comment: @TabAlleman also the form input type is 'datetime' and makes me put in a time and not just a date. I'm open to use whatever even if it's a range between two datetimes

Comment: @AdamRobinson I tried `UPDATE table SET newDateCol = STR_TO_DATE(oldDateTimeCol, '%W, %M %e, %Y');

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '2015-08-19 01:00:00' BETWEEN '2015-08-19' AND '2015-08-20' x;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

SELECT '2015-08-20 01:00:00' BETWEEN '2015-08-19' AND '2015-08-20' x;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 0 |
+---+
```